# Fix CSS/HTML for an email template

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix an email template and I cannot get the logo centered and on top of the table its on. The way it was written is confusing me and I keep making changes to it and I cannot get it right. If you can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what it looks like:

[image: CSS issue]

Here is the code I am trying to fix:

```html
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  td {
    width: 480px !important;
  }
}
</style>

  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#09afdf" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="background" style="height: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#09afdf" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="preheader">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="preheader_links">
                      <p style="color: #666666; font-size: 10px; line-height: 22px; text-align: right;">Unable to view this message? <a href="javascript:void(0)" :hover="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" style="color: #666666; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Click here</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="logo">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.color='#666666'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#514F4E'" style="color: #514F4E; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dya7pcwuu/image/upload/v1504207932/headerlogo_1_auznv6.png"></a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #preheader -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#FF0412" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="header_content">
                    <h1 style="color: #FFFEF7; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;">Submission</h1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- // END #header -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #header_container -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="body_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" class="body_content">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
                <tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <h2 style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 22px; text-align: center;"><%=@contact.subject%></h2>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Name: <%=@contact.name%></p>

    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Email: <%=@contact.email%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Phone: <%=@contact.phone%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Message: <%=@contact.message%></p>
  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- // END #body_container -->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- // END #background -->
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying the suggestions and it is still coming out like the image below. I even restarted the server and it still does. If you look at my code snippet it shows it as to the side but if you look at the image that is how it is actually coming out in the email. Every single suggestion the output is the same as the image below.

[image: error]

**UPDATE 2**
It appears it is being rendered as the image below because of something with the email client I am using which I cannot figure out.

Comment: `style` and `@media`? as far as I know every thing should be inline. Also if you want you can find here http://foundation.zurb.com/ framework for e-mail

Comment: This was in a bootstrap template for an email so not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `<center>` as suggested above, it is not supported in HTML5. I placed `text-align:center` in the logo's parent td and changed the logo to use `display:inline`.

Please consider separating your presentation from structure by moving all styling to css.

```html
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  td {
    width: 480px !important;
  }
}
</style>

  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#09afdf" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="background" style="height: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#09afdf" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="preheader">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="preheader_links">
                      <p style="color: #666666; font-size: 10px; line-height: 22px; text-align: right;">Unable to view this message? <a href="javascript:void(0)" :hover="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" style="color: #666666; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Click here</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600" style="text-align:center;">
                    <div class="logo" style="display:inline;">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.color='#666666'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#514F4E'" style="color: #514F4E; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dya7pcwuu/image/upload/v1504207932/headerlogo_1_auznv6.png"></a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #preheader -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#FF0412" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="header_content">
                    <h1 style="color: #FFFEF7; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;">Submission</h1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- // END #header -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #header_container -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="body_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" class="body_content">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
                <tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <h2 style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 22px; text-align: center;"><%=@contact.subject%></h2>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Name: <%=@contact.name%></p>

    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Email: <%=@contact.email%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Phone: <%=@contact.phone%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Message: <%=@contact.message%></p>
  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- // END #body_container -->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- // END #background -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following style to your `<td>` tag which is surrounding your logo image. This will put content of the `<td>` into the center.

```
style="text-align: center;"
```

`<td valign="top" width="600" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="logo">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.color='#666666'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#514F4E'" style="color: #514F4E; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="your_image_url"></a>
                    </div>
         </td>`

Comment: @JermaineSubia thanks for advice. I like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  td {
    width: 480px !important;
  }
}
</style>

  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#09afdf" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="background" style="height: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#09afdf" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="preheader">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="preheader_links">
                      <p style="color: #666666; font-size: 10px; line-height: 22px; text-align: right;">Unable to view this message? <a href="javascript:void(0)" :hover="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" style="color: #666666; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Click here</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="logo">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.color='#666666'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#514F4E'" style="color: #514F4E; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"><center><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dya7pcwuu/image/upload/v1504207932/headerlogo_1_auznv6.png"></center></a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #preheader -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#FF0412" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="header_content">
                    <h1 style="color: #FFFEF7; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;">Submission</h1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- // END #header -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #header_container -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="body_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" class="body_content">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
                <tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <h2 style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 22px; text-align: center;"><%=@contact.subject%></h2>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Name: <%=@contact.name%></p>

    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Email: <%=@contact.email%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Phone: <%=@contact.phone%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Message: <%=@contact.message%></p>
  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- // END #body_container -->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- // END #background -->
```

`<center></center>` fixed it

Comment: DO NOT USE `<center>` as it is not supported in HTML5. The logo is a block level element. Use margins to adjust its position.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }

  td {
    width: 480px !important;
  }
  
}
.logo a img {
    // center the image inside the div.logo by adding margin: auto
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>

  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#09afdf" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="background" style="height: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#09afdf" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="preheader">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="preheader_links">
                      <p style="color: #666666; font-size: 10px; line-height: 22px; text-align: right;">Unable to view this message? <a href="javascript:void(0)" :hover="text-decoration: underline;" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" style="color: #666666; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Click here</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="600">
                    <div class="logo">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myEvent();" onmouseover="this.style.color='#666666'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#514F4E'" style="color: #514F4E; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dya7pcwuu/image/upload/v1504207932/headerlogo_1_auznv6.png"></a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #preheader -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#FF0412" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="header">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="header_content">
                    <h1 style="color: #FFFEF7; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;">Submission</h1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!-- // END #header -->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- // END #header_container -->

        <table width="600" border="0" bgcolor="#fcfcfc" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" id="body_container">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" class="body_content">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
                <tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <h2 style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 22px; text-align: center;"><%=@contact.subject%></h2>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Name: <%=@contact.name%></p>

    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Email: <%=@contact.email%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Phone: <%=@contact.phone%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Message: <%=@contact.message%></p>
  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- // END #body_container -->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- // END #background -->
```

Comment: I have been running it and for some odd reason on my end the email is still coming out the same which I know it shouldn't.

Comment: check my udpate

Comment: I'm glad you've find a solution. My next suggestion would be to hardcode the same properties using the style attribute.